# How to test the AJAX file upload using iframe rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am uploading file using iframe, I want to test this functionality. Not getting how should I test it. Need help.

```
describe 'POST create' do
     context 'when the object is valid' do

       it 'should save the object', :js => true do
         pending('Yet to figure out how to test the AJAX file upload using iframe.')
       end
     end
end
```

Please let me know if you need any other information.